# Servicestack.Redis how to use GetRange feature

Tags: c#, servicestack.redis

I need to use the redis command [GETRANGE](https://redis.io/commands/getrange/).
I use it this retrieve the hash I store along with the string content, to evaluate if this latter has been changed while using side in memory cache.

Using ([RedisClient.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/b9a09632e0c5a9c46223854e8df9631595d77d6c/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisClient.cs)) I am unable to access get range function as it is not available

How can *GETRANGE* command be used when working with *RedisClient*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UTF-8 string APIs for `GetRange()` and `SetRange()` have now been added to `IRedisClient`:

```cs
public interface IRedisClient
{
    string Slice(string key, int fromIndex, int toIndex);
    long InsertAt(string key, int offset, string value);
    //...
}
```

and Async versions to:

```cs
public interface IRedisClientAsync
{
    ValueTask<string> SliceAsync(string key, int fromIndex, int toIndex, CancellationToken token = default);
    ValueTask<long> InsertAtAsync(string key, int offset, string value, CancellationToken token = default);
    //...
}
```

This change is available from v6.0.3 that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: From version 6.0.3 ([ServiceStack.Redis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Redis/)) the feature will be directly accessible from RedisClient.
*Thanks to mythz for the info.*

Exploring GitHub source code you can see that *RedisClient* extends *[RedisClientNative](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/b9a09632e0c5a9c46223854e8df9631595d77d6c/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisNativeClient.cs#L687)*, this latter do have the GetRange method available, so the first solution is as follow:

```
var nativeClient = redisClient as RedisNativeClient;
var prefix = nativeClient?.GetRange(key, from, to)?.FromUtf8Bytes();
```

This solution is nice and simple and possibly will always work, but we are relying on ServiceStack to always implement RedisClient extending RedisNativeClient, but we can't be 100% sure about it.

The alternative solution is to leverage the LUA script execution feature, where you can:

```
var prefix = redisClient.ExecLuaAsString("return redis.call('GETRANGE', ARGV[1], ARGV[2], ARGV[3])", key, from, to);
```

Performance wise the Native approach is slightly faster and uses less memory.

[image]

Comment: FYI RedisClient will always inherit RedisNativeClient [by design](https://docs.servicestack.net/redis/#api-overview).